# Listing all invites (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm looking to fetch all the invites created within a guild and paste all the invites into an embedded format, with just the invite links.

**Error**:  TypeError: invites.all is not a function

```
module.exports = {
  name: `listallinvs`,
  description: `Displays all the invites created within the server.`,
  async execute(message, args) {
   

    message.guild.fetchInvites().then((invites) => {
      let allInvites = invites.all();

      const printinvites = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .addField(`Invite URL: ${allInvites.url}`)
     

      message.channel.send(printinvites); 
    });
  },
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`fetchInvites`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchInvites) returns a [collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) of invites and it has no `.all()` method, that's why you received the error.

What you can do instead is to fetch all the invites, check if there are any, and if there are, iterate over them and create a new embed field for each. You can use [`.map()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=map) that returns a new array. You can use this array with the MessageEmbed's [`.addFields()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=addFields) method that accepts an array of objects (where the object has a `name` and a `value` key).

Check out the working code below:

```js
message.guild.fetchInvites().then((invites) => {
  if (!invites.size) return message.channel.send('No invites found');

  let allInvites = invites.map((i) => ({
    name: 'Invite',
    value: `**Inviter:** ${i.inviter}
      **Code:** [${i.code}](https://discord.gg/${i.code})
      **Used by:** ${i.uses} of ${i.maxUses === 0 ? '∞' : i.maxUses}
      **Expires on:** ${
        i.maxAge
          ? new Date(i.createdTimestamp + i.maxAge * 1000).toLocaleString()
          : 'never'
      }`,
    inline: true,
  }));

  message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed().addFields(allInvites));
});
```

[image]

You could also just add the invite links as the field values:

```js
let allInvites = invites.map((i) => ({
  name: 'Invite link',
  value: `https://discord.gg/${i.code}`,
}));

message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed().addFields(allInvites));
```

[image]

Or you could completely ditch the embed fields and just use the description

```js
let allInvites = invites.map((i) => `https://discord.gg/${i.code}`);

message.channel.send(
  new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Invite Links')
    .setDescription(allInvites.join('\n')),
);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really appreciate your help.